# Question about series.

Tags: number-theory

1. EDIT: I have deleted the first part of my question, to be honest, I dont know what I was thinking. Thanks for all the answers.
2. My second question is about the equality $$- \sum_{i=1}^{l} \log(1-p_{i}^{-1}) = \sum_{i=1}^{l} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(mp_{i}^m)^{-1}$$ Where $p_j$ is a prime. I dont see how this equality holds, can someone explain it for me? (It is part of a proof in my literature)

Comment: How do you argue that $\sum 1/n < \sum 1/p$? For the second question, do you know the Taylor series of $\log (1+x)$?

Comment: I made a fatal mistake, I will edit it in one second. @DanielFischer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is not going to work, it is incorrect. For example, $1/n^2 < 1/n$ for every $n$, so $\sum n^{-2}<\sum n^{-1}$, but $\sum n^{-2}$ *converges*. To show something diverges, you have to bound it from *below* by something that diverges, not from *above*. For the second question, we have that $$-\log(1-x)=\sum_{k\geqslant 1} \frac {x^k}k$$

whenever $|x|<1$. Do this for $1/p_i$, $p_i$ a prime.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, consider this:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/n = \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} +...$$
and 
$$\sum 1/p = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} +...$$

By the comparison test, since 1/n > 1/p, you cannot prove that since the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/n$ diverges, the series $\sum 1/p$ will also diverge.